# Masked text while keying in the data in jsf

Tags: jsf, text, mask

I'm trying to mask the text with star as they type in except the last character in jsf1.2 and richfaces.

I'm trying to use onkeyup event and mask it in the backing bean, however I'm having a hard time to auto refresh the component on each key stroke.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: What are you using as the input component? It may have an option to mask input.

Comment: i'm using h inputText with a4j support ajax component                 t <h:inputText id="idNo" value="#{bBean.idNo}">   <a4j:support event="onkeyup" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="idNo" actionListener="#{bBean.maskNo}"></a4j:support> </h:inputText>

Answer (score 0):

You should use the h:inputSecret component for this. This will render an HTML password input element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion james, i did look into that but my requirement is to not mask the last character until it losses the focus... what i'm trying to say is if i type a it should be a, ab it should be *b, abc it should be **c